# Use datasource of admin grid in another grid

Tags: grid, magento-2.2.5

In Magento 2.2.5, I am using datasource in the grid and it is working fine.

I want to use the same datasource in another grid with some filters. I am using `vendorname_module_deal_listing_data_source` again in the another grid. But it is keeps loading. I cannot find any errors in console and log anywhere.
Code of `di.xml` is:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="vendorname_module_deal_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendorname\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<virtualType name="Vendorname\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">module_manage_deal</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendorname\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

Update:

admin layout Code: https://pastebin.com/ZRw0ug9D

Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/kzqzov

Working Grid's UI Component: https://pastebin.com/Lb7QZmUt

Copied Grid's UI Component: https://pastebin.com/i3DXVita

Comment: so what is the issue?

Comment: I want to use same datasource  in another grid. But it is keeps loading

Comment: Can you add screenshot what you facing and please add code where you have used vendorname_module_deal_listing_data_source  in another module

Comment: @RutveeSojitra Pls check my updated code.

Comment: I don't think so this is the right way....

in another module where in ui_component folder in xml file  you need to add that datasource

Comment: Have you made second module layout file? and ui_comnet/.xml file?

Comment: Not in Anothermodule. In the same module, another grid.

Comment: Create different datasource with same collection : Vendorname\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Deal\Collection

Comment: Tried by creating another datasource too. Still same loading.

Comment: so you can directly use that datasource name dirctly over there no need to create any other collection

Comment: have you did upgrade,compile and deploy command

Comment: Post another grid code in question. May be small mistake over there

Comment: Please find my update question

Answer (score 0):

As per your original data source name:

In both file data source name should be  same like below:

```
                   <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendorname_module_deal_listing_data_source</argument>
```

but in copied code i am found diff datasource name:

```
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendorname_customergroup_deal_listing_data_source</argument>
```

Can you please check and make it same